# Large bitmap for background giving OOM error

Tags: android

I have a bitmap that I'm loading into the surfaceView that is around 75kb (give or take)

The code I'm using to call it or decode it is

```
bmLargeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.campplan);
```

nothing fancy really. The size of the image is 1000x500 pix. Which load fine when I want to. Problem is I want it to be 2000x1000 which is double that size.

I tried the resize with this code

```
bmLargeImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmLargeImage, 2000, 1000, true);
```

but it gives me a OOM error. I tried saving the png file as a 2000x1000 pix image and again it gives the OOM exception. This is tested in an emulator so far. But I think the size should be enough to load, what am I missing?

Note: I want it this big cause it's a background to a game (think like farmvile or smurf's village game background) so it should be big and scrollable, yet I only manage the 1000x500 size.

Comment: What is the heap size of the emulator? the minimum for phones is 16Mb but most devices have more. An image of size 2000x1000 can easily take up 8Mb of RAM. This is because the image is loaded in `RGBA_8888` format by default which stores, for each pixel, 4 bytes. On for each of the red, green, blue and alpha channels. Unless there is alpha in the image, `createScaledBitmap` will return an image in `RGB_565` format which will only cost 2 bytes per pixel. I believe when you are creating the scaled bitmap, you will also temporarily have two copies in memory making the memory usage even higher.

Comment: The size of the image (75kb) is irrelevant I might add. Unfortunately, there is no way around memory problems when dealing with large bitmaps. You have to be very careful with your memory usage. I suppose you could consider tiling your background image and loading the tiles as you need them and calling `recycle()` on the bitmaps you are finished with. EDIT - i meant to say 'temporarily have `both` copies in memory' in my last comment

Comment: true I guess. I hope to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

check this link http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android%E2%84%A2-application/ might be helpful to you as 
as there is some problem with createScaledBitmap http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13038

Comment: interesting. I'll have to try it out when I'm back to my laptop